# "Feature" (bug?) in R 3.6.1

Tags: r

Is this a bug or a feature..?

Reproducible example:

```
test <- data.frame(Time=1:10,Activity=runif(10))
head(test$Time)
names(test)[names(test)=="Time"]                      <- "Time_new"
head(test$Time)
```

Both calls produce the following output:
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

```
test <- data.frame(Time=1:10,Activity=runif(10))
head(test$Time)
names(test)[names(test)=="Time"]                      <- "new_Time"
head(test$Time)
```

The first call produces 
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

.. only the second produced
NULL

Weird!
Running on Linux Mint 19.1

Comment: Don't know if a feature, but it's deliberate and not a bug. You can use the first few letters of a variable name if it's unique. Try head(test\$new). This is an argument for referring to variables as test["Time_new"], rather than test\$Time_new.

Comment: It is better to use `[[` instead of partial matching

Comment: Partial matching is considered a feature. It's not new. See the help page at `?"$"` for documentation. The `name` argument of `$` is described as *"For extraction, this is normally (see under ‘Environments’) partially matched to the names of the object."* (The note is that partial matching is not done when extracting from environments)

Comment: did you accidentally paste the same code snippet twice ...?

Comment: ah.  The formatting confused me.  The assignments were so far to the right that I read them as comments ...

Comment: Took me a minute too. Thanks for finding the right dupe!